# SQL Trigger to allow only customers who are old enough to buy a book?

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

I have 3 tables, `person`, `audiobook` and `audiobook_purchases`. My database is running MariaDB.

- `person` has fields: `id`, `date_of_birth`;
- `audiobook` has fields: `ISBN`, `age_rating`, `title`;
- `audiobook_purchases` has fields: `ISBN`, `customer_id`, `date_of_purchase`;

I'm trying to write a trigger to make sure that when a customer tried to purchases an audiobook, they are old enough to do so according to the `age_rating` in audiobook.

For example, If Harry Potter and the Philosipher's Stone had age rating 16 and customer Jennifer (ID 1) with date of birth `2010-01-01` tried to purchase this book, this would not be allowed, but Dominick(ID 2) with date_of_birth  `1978-01-01` would be allowed.

Please could someone show me a way to run this trigger?

Comment: Question is pretty much unclear on what you are trying to do here. This is *generally* not the way we add Triggers. Also, `\n` characters should definitely be interfering with the Trigger definition.

Comment: The trigger is to determine whether a customer, who is trying to buy an audiobook, is old enough to purchase this audiobook. Their date of birth is stored in the 'person' table and the age rating for an audiobook is in the 'audiobook' table. I want to prevent insertion of an entry in the 'audiobook_purchases' table if they are not old enough.

Comment: Please edit the question; add table structure details of the concerned tables. Add some sample data. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: How do you edit the question?

Comment: Just below the question, you can see a text saying "Edit" (besides "Share"). You can also use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53462268/edit

Comment: I added more context

Answer (score 1):

I don't know MariaDB in particular, so my answer may need some adjustments.

You want to create an insert trigger on `audiobook_purchase` so that a new order will be inserted only if the person who wants to place the order is old enough according to `audiobook.age_rating`.

First you need to figure out a way of extracting the year from `person.date_of_birth`. Something like the `YEAR()` scalar function will probably be available. MariaDB may also provide a `NOW()` function, which gives the current date. So the person age right now will be: `YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(person.date_of_birth)`.

Then you have to write the insert trigger. The tricky part is to query the `person` table to get the person `date_of_birth` from his `id`, then to compare it to `audiobook.age_rating`.

Let's set out an example. First we declare the tables schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE person(id, name, date_of_birth);
CREATE TABLE audiobook(isbn, age_rating, title);
CREATE TABLE audiobook_purchases(isbn, customer_id, date_of_purchase);
```

Then we put in some data:

```
INSERT INTO person VALUES (10, "jennifer", '2010-01-01');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (20, "dominick", '1978-01-01');
INSERT INTO audiobook VALUES (1234, 16, "harry potter");
```

Then we create the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_purchases
AFTER INSERT ON audiobook_purchases
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (
    SELECT strftime('%Y', 'now') - strftime('%Y', date_of_birth) AS age
    FROM person 
    WHERE new.customer_id=person.id) < (
        SELECT audiobook.age_rating
        FROM audiobook
        WHERE audiobook.isbn=new.isbn)
BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM audiobook_purchases
    WHERE isbn=new.isbn AND 
    customer_id=new.customer_id AND
    date_of_purchase=new.date_of_purchase;
END;
```

I'll broke down the trigger into smaller steps:

1. `AFTER INSERT ON audiobook_purchases` creates a trigger on table `audiobook_purchases` which will be triggered after the insertion of a new record.
2. `FOR EACH ROW` applies the trigger to each new record inserted.
3. The `WHEN` clause limits triggering only to those records who satisfy its condition. On the left side of the `<` sign of the condition there is a query which selects the age of the customer. On the right side there is a query which selects the age rating of the book. Notice the reference to a `new` table. This table stores the record which triggers the event (see the two examples below). `strftime` is a scalar function which formats datetime stamps in SQLite. You can read: 
   `strftime('%Y', 'now')` as `YEAR(NOW())` and
   `strftime('%Y', date_of_birth)` as `YEAR(date_of_birth)`.
4. Finally between `BEGIN` and `END` there are instructions that will be executed on triggering. In this case there is a single instruction which removes the record just inserted. MariaDb may provide a `ROLLBACK` statement, which can be more efficient than the `DELETE` statement.

So, for example:

```
INSERT INTO audiobook_purchases VALUES (1234, 10, '2018-11-25');
```

will activate the trigger, because the customer with `id=10` ('jennifer') is 8 years old and the book with `isbn=1234` requires the customer to be at least 16 years old, while:

```
INSERT INTO audiobook_purchases VALUES (1234, 20, '2018-11-25');
```

will not activate the trigger, because this customer is 40 years old.

You must be aware that this solution silently ignore the invalid order. I don't know if this is your desired behaviour.

I tested this trigger on SQLite 3.11.0, so it may not be compatible with your SQL interpreter.